# Converting Oracle Reports to SSRS - Report Triggers Equivalent

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have been tasked with converting some old Oracle Reports into SSRS.
In Oracle Reports, there are report triggers, in particular a "Before Report" trigger that is used to fill parameter values.

I need to accomplish the same thing in SSRS.

Comment: Ignoring Oracle for a moment, how do you **want** to populate your parameters?

Comment: I am accepting 2 report parameters, and then I want to populate other parameters based on the value of those two parameters. I'm not sure if that is the proper way to go about it; It's how the Oracle report is handling it, and I'm just trying to get an SSRS to function the same way. If there is a better way, I'm open to suggestions.